# Microsoft Cognitive Image Search API - filtering result to specific website

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

we use Microsoft Cognitive services to create automated search requests to Bing.

Web Search works fine as we are able to filter results to a specific site:

> https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=Donald Duck
>   site:etsy.com&count=10

What I'm not able to do is do the same with the image search api:

> https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=
>   site:artfire.com&count=10&modulesRequested=similarimages&imgUrl=https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/8236745/iusa_400x400.6291711.jpg

Can you assist? How do I search for similar images in a specific destination site?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Bing Search doesn'tt support these for non-query based image-searches (i.e search by image-binary, search by image-url etc).

This is not an API specific limitation, it applies to www.Bing.com/images  as well. In general, what’s not supported on www.bing.com/images  will not be supported in image-API either

Comment: I have it working using imgUrl without the query parameter, but i cant make it work with the image in the post body.